# Duda rápida con else if que no me funcionan :(

Tags: java, condiciones, else

Sé de antemano que hay formas más optimizadas de hacer esto pero lo practico esto por entender el funcionamiento de este lenguaje. La duda: Meto un dinero y me devuelve Cuál es el producto más caro que se puede comprar + la vuelta. Pues no me funcionan los else if salvo el primero o responde directamente con el else. X ejemplo introduzco 1.7 y me devuelve el 1er else if. Gracias de antemano.

```
dCofla = prompt("Hola COFLA, ingresa tu dinero para ver el helado mas caro que puedas 
comprar");
dCofla = parseInt(dCofla);

if (dCofla >= 0.6 && dCofla < 1) {
alert("te da para el helao de agua y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 0.6));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1 && dCofla < 1.6) {
alert("te da para el helado de crema y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.6 && dCofla < 1.7) {
alert("te da para el bombon DIX y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.6));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.7 && dCofla < 1.8) {
alert("te da para el bombon Vich y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.7));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.8 && dCofla < 2.9) {
alert("te da para el Helardo y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.8));
}
else if (dCofla >= 2.9) {
alert("te da para el helado de Confites o un pote de 1/4kg y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 2.9));
}
else {
alert("no te da pa naaaaa");
}
```

Comment: Duda resuelta, todo se debía a ese parseInt que convertía todos los valores decimales de mi código a enteros. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido te invito a realizar el respectivo [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ver como realizar una
correcta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , procura no agregar comentarios en la zona de respuesta, mas aun si alguna de las respuestas te  fue de utilidad recuerda marcar el simbolo de check  ✓ . saludos

Answer (score 0):

Los precios son valores decimales. Cambia `parseInt` por `parseFloat`

```js
dCofla = prompt("Hola COFLA, ingresa tu dinero para ver el helado mas caro que puedas comprar");
dCofla = parseFloat(dCofla);

if (dCofla >= 0.6 && dCofla < 1) {
    alert("te da para el helao de agua y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 0.6));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1 && dCofla < 1.6) {
    alert("te da para el helado de crema y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.6 && dCofla < 1.7) {
    alert("te da para el bombon DIX y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.6));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.7 && dCofla < 1.8) {
    alert("te da para el bombon Vich y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.7));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.8 && dCofla < 2.9) {
    alert("te da para el Helardo y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.8));
}
else if (dCofla >= 2.9) {
    alert("te da para el helado de Confites o un pote de 1/4kg y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 2.9));
}
else {
    alert("no te da pa naaaaa");
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, tienes razón, veo que ese Parse Int convertía en entero hasta los limites decimales escritos en mi código, de ahí las consecuencias. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás usando `parseInt` que te devuelve un **Integer**,
Un Integer es un número entero, por lo que al ingresar 1.7 te lo trunca hacia 1.

Al castear la entrada debes utilizar un tipo de dato **double**. Esto lo puedes conseguir con la función `parseFloat()`

```
dCofla = prompt("Hola COFLA, ingresa tu dinero para ver el helado mas caro que puedas 
comprar");
dCofla = parseFloat(dCofla);

if (dCofla >= 0.6 && dCofla < 1) {
alert("te da para el helao de agua y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 0.6));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1 && dCofla < 1.6) {
alert("te da para el helado de crema y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.6 && dCofla < 1.7) {
alert("te da para el bombon DIX y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.6));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.7 && dCofla < 1.8) {
alert("te da para el bombon Vich y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.7));
}
else if (dCofla >= 1.8 && dCofla < 2.9) {
alert("te da para el Helardo y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 1.8));
}
else if (dCofla >= 2.9) {
alert("te da para el helado de Confites o un pote de 1/4kg y tu vuelto es de " + (dCofla - 2.9));
}
else {
alert("no te da pa naaaaa");
}
```

Comment: Sí es verdad me acabo de dar cuenta del Parse Int que convertía en entero todo mi código, reglas incluidas. Muchísimas gracias